# Item alignments changed when using stackpanel instead of dockpanel

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, stackpanel, dockpanel

I am working on an  implementation where I want to display some items in a window as shown below

```
---------------------
|                   |
|                   |   
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
| xx xx       xx xx |
|--------------------
```

The attached scrrenn shot also displays the same . However I need to somehow implement this using a stack panel instead of a dock panel

eve though I can get it to work as required from a dock panel when using stack panel is messes up all the alignments .

Here is a ss of the required way it should look [image]

this is what it looks like in a stack panel     [image]

below is my code , can anyone help me with this ?

```
<Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <TextBlock>  Text01  </TextBlock>

                <TextBlock>  Text02  </TextBlock>


            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" >

                <TextBlock>  Text03  </TextBlock>

                <TextBlock>  Text04  </TextBlock>


            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to force StackPanel to do what it doesn't support. Try Grid:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Text 01"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Text 02"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Text 03"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Text 04"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @ASh ! It most certainly does work. Any idea why when implementing with stack panel is behaves that way ?

Comment: @Devss, it is called -stack- panel for a reason. each child element (nested stackpanel) of *vertical* stackpanel occupies one horizontal strip: takes minimum required height and *entire* width. areas occupied by different elements cannot overlap. they are stacked. it is by design.